# How to parse a JSON object for a string

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON object

```
{
    "data": [{
        "user_id":"1",
        "user_name":"test",
        "user_phone":"2147483647",
        "user_email":"test@example.com"
    }]
}
```

and a jQuery loop function

```
$.each(responseData, function(index, ProfileData) {
    profiles.push(
        application.getModel("Profile", [ ProfileData.user_id, ProfileData.user_name, ProfileData.user_phone, ProfileData.user_email ] )
    );
});
```

But when the JSON object becomes this

```
{
    "data": [{
        "firm_id":"1",
        "firm_name":"Firm",
        "firm_phone":"2147483647",
        "firm_email":"testfirm@example.com"
    }]
}
```

Then I want to check whether the JSON data has `user` or `firm` extensions, and also need to use this in the `push()` instead.

```
application.getModel( "Profile", [ ProfileData.user_id, ProfileData.user_name, ProfileData.user_phone, ProfileData.user_email ] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the existence of a property inside an object like so:

```
if('user_id' in ProfileData)
```

So your solution might look like this:

```
$.each(responseData, function(index, ProfileData) {
    if('user_id' in ProfileData) {
        profiles.push(
            application.getModel("Profile", [ ProfileData.user_id, ProfileData.user_name, ProfileData.user_phone, ProfileData.user_email ] );
        );
     } else {
        profiles.push(
            application.getModel("Profile", [ ProfileData.firm_id, ProfileData.firm_name, ProfileData.firm_phone, ProfileData.firm_email ] );
        );
     }
});
```

Another approach would be to coalesce the different properties, and use whichever one is defined:

```
$.each(responseData, function(index, ProfileData) {
    profiles.push(
        application.getModel("Profile", [ 
            ProfileData.user_id    || ProfileData.firm_id, 
            ProfileData.user_name  || ProfileData.firm_name, 
            ProfileData.user_phone || ProfileData.firm_phone, 
            ProfileData.user_email || ProfileData.firm_email
        ] );
    );
});
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but regarding your comment, javascript array of javascript objects = JSON.

Comment: JSON generally means "JavaScript Object Notation" ... which covers both the object literal notation inside Javascript and the string representation of this object (e.g. using JSON.stringify())

Comment: Thank you David for the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem exists in the way you organize you json data. You might need to split user and firm in json. However, in the case you can not control the format of json, you could check if some data, such as 'user_id', contained in the data object before handling it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my way of doing it.

```
var responseData = {
    "data": [{
        "user_id": "1",
        "user_name": "test",
        "user_phone": "2147483647",
        "user_email": "test@example.com"}]
};

$.each(responseData.data, function(index, dataRow) {
    var getModelDataArray = [];

    $.each(dataRow, function(key, profileData){
        getModelDataArray.push(profileData);
    });

    profiles.push(application.getModel("Profile", getModelDataArray));
});
```

To be able to use this method, you need to know what data you can expect to get from the server. Otherwise you might end up using getModel() with an incorrect getModelDataArray. This code can be found in a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jchCP/5/).