# Parsing JSON parameters in Android

Tags: java, android, json

```
{"vsUserName":"d475","vsPassword":"8080","vsIPAddress":"192.168.1.1"}
```

This is the key value pairs that I have to parse in Android and used to login and password. I am new in android so no knowledge of parsing in android.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting usernames and passwords.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse JSONArray in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a JSON object for a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502781/how-to-parse-a-json-object-for-a-string)

Comment: Its Fake User name and Password .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should take a look at this - http://www.javatpoint.com/android-json-parsing-tutorial

your json like - {"vsUserName":"d475","vsPassword":"8080","vsIPAddress":"192.168.1.1"}

with help of - http://hayageek.com/android-http-post-get/

try this may be this could be helpful.. i'm not tested it -- pls let me know if problem persist -  The steps to do it below -

Follow the steps to send HTTP POST requests.
1. Create an object of HttpClient

2. Create an object of HttpPost
3. Add POST parameters with url
4. Finally making an HTTP POST request

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to parse JSON into model, then you can use google gson library its easy to use.

{"vsUserName":"d475","vsPassword":"8080","vsIPAddress":"192.168.1.1"}

Other approach is to parse json manually as:

Get the json object first

```
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

then get key-value pairs

```
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("STRINGNAME");
```

and so on...

For further assistance you can visit this link

[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: what is result here ??

Answer (score 0):

```
    Boolean bIsSuccess = false; // Write according to your logic this is demo.

    public void parseResponse(JSONObject response) {

        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
            bIsSuccess = jObject.getBoolean("success");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Class.this, "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Test
        }

    }
```